# Can't edit file with all permissions

Tags: linux, files, permissions, vim

I have a file with 777 permissions:

```
ls -la /path/to/file
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39068 Mar  8 15:30 /path/to/file
```

But for some reason I can't edit it. Inside vi it says `E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)` when I try to save. Why can't I edit it? I don't have sudo permissions but I should be able to edit it.

Comment: Is the file already opened in a Vim session? You may have used `Ctrl+Z` in some other session to temporarily suspend it, and then forgotten about it?  What are your permissions on the directory that contain the file?

Comment: What does `getfacl /path/to/file` say? Can you `ed` or `nano` the file?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I don't have it open in another session. I also don't have `getfacl`, `ed` or `nano` installed. I can't even `rm` the file

Comment: What is the permissions and ownership on the directory that contain the file?

Comment: Of the parent directory: `drwxr-x---`

Comment: as mention in your comment, if filesystem is readonly, you will have to mount it read-write. we need more details (CD or DVD ? remote network resource ? ) what does `df /path/to ` says ?

Comment: It says: `df: Warning: cannot read table of mounted file systems: No such file or directory
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
-               20961280 3706480  17254800  18% /nfs
`

Comment: It looks like that's some kind of container in which `/proc` is not mounted. Can you confirm you have no privileged access to that system (`su`, `sudo`, login as root...)? The `mount` command just prints an error message, right? Please, edit your question when adding new information instead of writing it in comments.

Comment: @fra-san It's a (Singularity) container. `/proc` is empty. Should it contain something?

Comment: `mount` would read from `/proc/self/mountinfo` to tell us more about how the file system you are on is mounted (refer to `man 5 proc` for more on it). But it's probably irrelevant, it seems you are supposed not to modify things there. I guess you'll have to take some other route to achieve your final goal.